# Google Spreadsheet getFeed error and comprehension

Tags: java, authentication, nullpointerexception, spreadsheet

I am trying to work with Google Spreadsheets but I've come across an issue I cannot comprehend.

Below is the code before I explain my self:

```
SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
//service.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+credential.getRefreshToken());

// TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

// Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

// Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
SpreadsheetFeed feed = null;
try {
    feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

// Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
  // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
  System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to read the Spreadsheets available at the account that the variable credential points to. I have both the AccessToken and RefreshToken there.

What happens when I run the code is that the Try Catch goes into Catch with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
at DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:69)
```

I've played with the functions in service variable, as you can see I have one line commented. I've tried with AccessToken instead of RefreshToken and it still gives me the error I've written above.

I cannot comprehend this error: 
Where does it come from?
Why does it happen?
How can I fix it?

It'd be great if anyone could help me. I'll come back with more information if I have any.

Comment: are you using `xoauth_requestor_id` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I don't know. How can i tell?

Comment: look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-documents-list-api/BdzYdNz6I3Q

Comment: Will look into it! I'll be back later with an answer. Thanks for the help so far :)
Edit: I've read it but I do not have any reference to that. I am using the latest gdata-java-client as I've downloaded it yesterday from this url https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-src.java-1.47.1.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been proudly **solved**:

Ok so my mistake - Feeds.

I am using OAth2 and when you redirect a user so you can retrieve the Access token it has SCOPES attached to it, meaning what kind of permissions will you give to the app. I was missing the following last two referring to feeds:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "https://docs.google.com/feeds",
  "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
```

As seen on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=pt-BR under "Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0".

Another thing to point out is that there seems to be some problem with some users regarding:

```
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

So one way to fix it is to refresh token before calling it like so:

```
credential.refreshToken();
srv.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

I hope whoever encounters this post finds the information above useful! :)

Have a great day, coder!